# How to publish code coverage and test result in Azure devops wiki

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-wiki

My requirement is when my build pipeline completes the unit test and coverage report and same need to be published to Azure Devops Wiki. Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same. Is there any task available in azure pipeline to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Azure Pipeline tasks available for this purpose publish to the pipeline itself, wherein results are displayed in the **Tests** tab in the pipeline summary.

If you want to publish it to an ADO Wiki, you could probably add a command line task and invoke appropriate REST APIs to [Get Build Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code-coverage/get-build-code-coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) / [Get Test Run Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code-coverage/get-test-run-code-coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and then [Update your Wiki page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).